# My utterance was overlapping by multiple entities

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I have an intent "Top_10_procurement_packages", there is a utterance "" which exists multiple entities.

[image: project_top_10_procurement_packages]

I've found that I am able to remove many entities. even I removed all of them and reset my expected entity. after training, this issue is still there.

Any solution for it.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your issue. Can you provide an example? 1) What utterance are you using? 2) What entities is it actually detecting for which words in the utterance? 3) What entities do you want it to detect for which words? 4) What entities did you remove to try and fix this?